# Check if cookie is a session cookie and if cookie was generated on current page or carried over from a previous page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to check if a cookie is a session cookie AND if that cookie was generated on the current page or if it carried over from another page.

I want to check for this on the client side using JavaScript.

I know I can get some info from the dev tools, however I need to get the data within my script and send it in a request to another api.

I am wondering if the only way to check is checking if these values are present in the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

If there is no expires OR path properties, I can assume it’s a session cookie and generated on the current page?

Comment: I don't think JS can get any information about the cookie, just its value.

Comment: Why not use `localStorage` to keep track of cookie value and page?